# Primality of a two generated ideal (in a UFD).

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

(1) Let $A$ be a UFD, $a \in A$ irreducible(=prime). It is well-known (and easily shown) that $Aa$, the ideal of $A$ generated by $a$, is a prime ideal.

If $a_1,a_2 \in A$ are irreducible, what can be said about $Aa_1+Aa_2$? Namely, is it a prime ideal? I guess there are counterexamples.

(2) Let $R$ be a (noetherian) UFD, $T$ an indeterminate, and $h \in R[T]$ irreducible of degree $\geq 2$.

- When $h'$ is also irreducible?
- Is the ideal of $R[T]$ generated by $h$ and $h'$ a prime ideal?

Any comment is welcome. (I apologize if my questions are somewhat trivial).

**Edit:** A similar question can be found [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60957/how-to-determine-whether-an-ideal-is-prime-or-not-by-an-algorithm).

Comment: Have you tried the case when $R$ is a field? It seems to me that then $(h,h')=1$ (in characteristic zero).

Comment: Truly, I have written a few words on that case, but than deleted them. However, in second thought it's better to have that comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I would suggest that you work some of these out instead of being too optimistic.

For 1), take for example, $A=k[x,y]$, $a_1=x-y^2, a_2=x$, both are prime, but $Aa_1+Aa_2$ is not.

For 2), again take $R=k[x]$ so that $R[y]=A$ as above. Consider for the first bullet, $h(y)=y^3-x^2$. Then $h$ is irreducible, but $h'(y)=3y^2$ is not. For the last one, take $h(y)=y^2-x^3$, again irreducible, but so is $h'(y)=2y$ (characteristic not 2). But the ideal generated by $h,h'$ is not prime.

Comment: Thanks! For my last question, do you think there is a chance to obtain the following claim: The ideal generated by $h$ and $h'$ is a prime ideal if and only if $R \to R[T]/(h)$ is ...? Please notice that: The ideal generated by $h$ and $h'$ is $R[T]$ if and only if $R \to R[T]/(h)$ is formally smooth; please see Jason Starr's comment in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/217581/smoothness-of-a-to-at-h#comment536038_217581.